# How to install firefox in precise64 vagrant box

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, virtualbox, vagrant, apt

I want to use `selenium-webdriver` with `chrome` or `firefox` in precise 64 bit box.

At first I must install `firefox`, so I followed this instraction.
http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/

I added `ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then `sudo apt-get update`.

But then I got this error.

```
E: Type 'ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I also tried `add-apt-repository` but it fails with `command not found` error.

How can do to install firefox to precise64? Or is it better if I use another box for using selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing firefox will cause a lot of dependencies to be installed, .e.g X and a desktop environment or at least a light weight WM.

In fact, 12.04.4 LTS already has firefox 28.0 in its official repository, you don't have to add a PPA to get the latest stable, just do `sudo apt-get -y install firefox` and it'll do.

BTW: You are getting the error because it's not the correct line(s) to be added in sources.list or split files under /etc/sources.list.d/*.list

it should be like below:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu precise main
```

To use `add-apt-repository` command, you'll have to install `python-software-properties` beforehand.

Comment: Somehow without adding ppa, I couldn't install firefox. After installing it I have still problem with `xvfb`. But at least I know now how to install firefox. Thanks!